# can I say this is a rotation

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

If $f:B(0,1)\to B(0,1)$ is a bijective holomorphic function such that $f^{-1}$ is also holomorphic.Can I say that $f$ is a rotation?

Comment: Most definitely not. Look up [Blaschke factors](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BlaschkeFactor.html).

Comment: You did not define $B(0,1)$. Circle of rad 1 about 0? In order to call some map a rotation, this map should preserve distanses. What distance does it preserve?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, this is false. We can, however, describe all of the automorphisms of the unit disk using the [Schwarz lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma). Note that this gives you conditions under which $f$ is a rotation - that is $f(0) = 0$ and $|f(z)| = |z|$ for some nonzero $z \in B(0, 1)$. There is another sort of automorphism of $B(0, 1)$ defined as follows: let $a \in B(0, 1)$ and define $f_a(z) = \frac{a - z}{1 - \overline{a} z}$. This is an automorphism of $B(0, 1)$. This requires some checking using the maximum modulus principle to conclude that it actually maps into $B(0, 1)$ and the Schwarz lemma to conclude that it is its own inverse. We claim that every such automorphisms looks like $e^{i \theta} f_a$ for some $\theta, a$.

This proof is taken from Stein and Shakarchi's *Complex Analysis* Theorem 2.2. Let $f: B(0, 1) \longrightarrow B(0, 1)$ be an automorphism. Then there is some $a \in B(0, 1)$ such that $f(a) = 0$. Consider now $g = f \circ f_a$ and observe that $g(0) = f(f_a(0)) = f(a) = 0$. Then by the Schwarz lemma, $|g(z)| \leq |z|$. Furthermore, applying the Schwarz lemma to $g^{-1}$ yields $|g^{-1}(z)| \leq |z|$, so $|z| = |g^{-1}(g(z))| \leq |g(z)|$ so $|g(z)| = |z|$. Hence, $g$ is a rotation (again by the Schwarz lemma). Recall that we had $f \circ f_a = g$. As $f_a = f_a^{-1}$, $f = g \circ f_a$ as desired.